# By a false move, I disabled a Java class under IntelliJ. How to reactivate it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I did a wrong move with my keyboard or mouse, and now a class of mine appears disabled on *IntelliJ*.

I watched the right context menu but found no clues about how to reactivate it.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you moved it, and it's now showing as untracked by git? Try `git status`, maybe that will tell you what changed. There isn't really a "disabled" class concept in IntelliJ AFAIK.

Comment: Hover over the icon (i.e. point at it with the mouse, but don't click on it). IntelliJ should show a popup with an explanation. Please add that explanation to your post.

Comment: Humm... I was coding in other projects, and just noticed that it came back blue... I've checked before : the file wasn't deleted, nor in `.gitignore`